# Typecasting the output in Python

Tags: python, casting

Here in my code I am getting output something like `<generator object <genexpr>` and I dont know why. I tried to cast it to some tuple or list but still the same problem.

```
for example:
>>> 5 1000          //where n = 5 is number of points, p = 1000 the money which already exists
>>> 386 780 0       //x,y,m and we just care about m here and if m of any point is bigger than p, 
    494 160 1215    //we append the point to the list l
    313 573 1553
    216 506 750
    355 506 1630
```

output should be number of points '2 3 5' but I'm getting this:

```
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x012AB610> <generator object <genexpr> at 0x012AB5A0> <generator object <genexpr> at 0x012AB648>
```

My code:

```
import random
random.seed(42)
n, p = list(map(int, input().split()))
x = []
y = []
m = []
l = set()

for i in range(0, n):
    a1, a2, a3 = list(map(int, input().split()))
    x.append(a1)
    y.append(a2)
    m.append(a3)
points = [random.random() for _ in range(n)]
for v in m:
     if v > p:
         l.add(v(point) for point in points)

print(*l)
print(len(l))
```

Comment: You are using a generator expression to create generator objects... Do you know what that means? If not, I suggest not using generators

Comment: are you using a set on purpose too? Sets don't allow only unique values

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yeah I know it's a generator. I am just trying to append those points which its m > p and I only found out this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`v(point)` won't work because `v` is an integer, not a function. The expression `v(point) for point in points` is creating a generator object which is why it's not throwing an error.

It seems to me that you are trying to add the points for inputs where `m` is greater than `p`. You can do so by using `enumerate`:

```
import random
random.seed(42)
n, p = list(map(int, input().split()))
x = []
y = []
m = []
l = set()

for i in range(0, n):
    a1, a2, a3 = list(map(int, input().split()))
    x.append(a1)
    y.append(a2)
    m.append(a3)
points = [random.random() for _ in range(n)]
for idx, v in enumerate(m):
     if v > p:
         l.add(points[idx])

print(*l)
print(len(l))
```

Answer (score 2):

`v(point) for point in points` is a generator expression. You don't get the output unless you do something that iterates over it.

You should iterate over it, and add each element.

```
for v in m:
    if v > p:
        for point in points:
            l.add(point)
```

Comment: I've already tried that before but I get this error ``` l.add(tuple(v(point) for point in points))
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable```

Comment: That's a different problem. What is `v(point)` supposed to mean?

Comment: Maybe you meant `v[point]`? I can't really follow what your code is doing.

Comment: Sorry I did a mistake here, it should be point(v). it means the point of object v. I am trying to append those points which its m > p and I only found out this method. I would like to know if there's other useful methods

Comment: `point(v)` doesn't make sense either. `point` is a random number, not a function.

Comment: Shouldn't the point be the `x` and `y` values from the same input line as `v`?

Comment: What are the random numbers for, how do they relate to the original problem?

Comment: I also tried before to iterate through all the points as what you did the way above but it doesn't work because it prints the entire set of points

Comment: I generate random points and assign x,y,m to them.  but in this problem there's no use from x and y